# Set timepicker value programmatically

Tags: win-universal-app, timepicker, windows-10-mobile

I have a timepicker component in my app and I want to set the time with a string I receive from my server. Something like: "12:45" (HH:MM)

My timepicker, in xaml, appears as:

```
<TimePicker Name="Wake_TimePicker" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="1" MaxWidth="90" Margin="0,20,0,0" Header="Wake Hour" />
```

But I don't know how to change the value it shows when I load my page. I want to show the hour and minutes I got from my server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you can do this with something like this:

```
TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(serverHour,serverMinutes,0);
Wake_TimePicker.Time = ts;
```

You can put this code after `InitializeComponent();`

Comment: Thank you, it works. I will check about timeSpan class.